# Generate 3 random numbers

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying generate three random numbers using `WITH` operator.

```
 WITH loop(n) AS (
   SELECT 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT CAST(ABS(RANDOM() % 1E2) AS INTEGER) FROM loop
   LIMIT 3
 )
 SELECT group_concat(n) FROM loop;
```

But every time my code returns something like `1, 81, 63` or `1, 9, 28`, in other words the first number in sequence is not random. It seems that my issue is covered in `SELECT` operator but at the moment I don't have any idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 1, which starts the CTE, is hard-coded in a select, which explains why your set of three numbers always starts with 1.  Try making the seed select also a random number:

```
WITH loop(n) AS (
    SELECT CAST(ABS(RANDOM() % 1E2) AS INTEGER)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(ABS(RANDOM() % 1E2) AS INTEGER) FROM loop
    LIMIT 3
)

SELECT group_concat(n) FROM loop;
```